# What is the maximum syntax formulas that I can use in calculated column on my Sharepoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, modern-experience, calculated-column-formula

I have created 20 syntax formulas (**IF(AND([Job Group]**=) based upon two other columns on my calculated column field, but I seemed to have reached a maximum limit.

I cannot load my 21st syntax formula as it immediately gives me an error message. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Across all SharePoint, there is a maximum limit of a text in a textfield **256** characters. Can you check if you did not overcrossed it?

Comment: Maximum text characters are not the issue. Definitely a formula length. I did test the workaround for limit nested and it worked, however, my column now includes a FALSE statement next to each formulas response.

Answer (score 0):

As per [What is the workaround for limit in nested if statements in sharepoint calculated column?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/231997/what-is-the-workaround-for-limit-in-nested-if-statements-in-sharepoint-calculate),

- Maximum nested IFs: SharePoint 2007 and 2010 only allow 7. SharePoint 2013 and later (including Online) allows **19**. Larger values are possible by using batches of 7 or 19 or less and concatenating or adding the results.
- Maximum formula length: SharePoint 2007 and 2010 only allow 1024 characters. (2013 and later is around one billion!)

Make sure you are not crossing the limits of nested IFs in your formula.