# SharePoint Online - Multiple Nested If Statement in Custom List Calculated Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I'm new to the forum. Nice to be here. Hope someone can help me.

I'm trying to apply the following nested If statement to a calculated column in an SPO list. The formula works fine in Excel (with cell references in place of column references), but I can't get it to be accepted in an SPO calculated column. I've just read that anything above 7 nested If statements need to be broken up before the calculated column will accept them, but however I try I can't get it to be accepted.

If someone can help me with a syntax that works, it will be a massive help.

```
=IF([Superseded:(on same DWB)]="",IF([Declined: Comments]="",IF([Withdrawn: Comments]="",IF([Pending Approval]="",IF([Compliance Date]="",IF([Dispensation Required?]="",
IF([+/- Days]<-31, "Approved", IF(AND([+/- Days]>=-31,[+/- Days]< 0), "Approaching Expiry", 
IF(AND([+/- Days]>0,[Type of Request]="Breach"),"Ended", "Review Due"))),"Dispensation Required"),"Compliant"),"Awaiting Approval"),"Withdrawn"),"Declined"),"Superseded")
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any error while using above formula? Can you try replacing all `,` in your formula and use `;` instead?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ganesh. I've tried replacing ',' with ';' but still get the same error message: "Sorry, something went wrong. The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported." As I mentioned, I think it is possibly to do with the fact I have more than 7 nested If statements in the formula. I read that a workaround is to split the If statements into groups of no more than 7, but I can't figure out the syntax for that.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? As per this thread. In SP 2013/2016/2019 and online, you can use up to 19 nested levels of IF: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/231997/what-is-the-workaround-for-limit-in-nested-if-statements-in-sharepoint-calculate

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. I understand that you can have up to 19 nested levels of IF, but the author of the solution in that thread is batching his IFs. What I'm struggling with is the correct syntax to batch the IFs in my formula, so the calculated column accepts it. I'm looking for some help with that.

Comment: check my answer given below. let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using calculated formula in below format:

```
=IF(
    [Superseded:(on same DWB)]="",
    IF(
        [Declined: Comments]="",
        IF(
            [Withdrawn: Comments]="",
            IF(
                [Pending Approval]="",
                IF(
                    [Compliance Date]="",
                    IF(
                        [Dispensation Required?]="",
                        "",
                        "Dispensation Required"
                    ),
                    "Compliant"
                ),
                "Awaiting Approval"
            ),
            "Withdrawn"
        ),
        "Declined"
    ),
    "Superseded"
) &
IF(
    [+/- Days]<-31,
    "Approved",
    IF(
        AND([+/- Days]>=-31,[+/- Days]< 0),
        "Approaching Expiry",
        IF(
            AND([+/- Days]>0,[Type of Request]="Breach"),
            "Ended",
            "Review Due"
        )
    )
)
```

You can also remove the new lines and spaces from above formula.

**Documentation**: [Introduction to SharePoint calculated formulas and functions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introduction-to-sharepoint-formulas-and-functions-94e1b4cc-cd1c-49c2-80ec-90c9b9591f47)

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. I'm still getting exactly the same error message though unfortunately.

Comment: Update Ganesh - I've realised that one of the column names was spelled slightly incorrectly. Once I updated that it accepted the original full formula - which is great. Unfortunately though it doesn't seem to be processing the IF statements relating to the [+/- Days} column. Could that be down to the name of the column do you think?

Comment: Yes. maybe issues with display name of column using operators (+, /, -). Can you try renaming these column and use new names in formula just to be sure?

Comment: Still the same problem unfortunately Ganesh. It is setting the calculated column result to 'Review Due', irrespective of the number of days in the '+/- Days' (now Days Difference) column. Frustrating! :-)

Comment: What is the result when no. of days are less than `-31`?

Comment: That part of the formula should show one of three results, or 'Review Due' if none of the three scenarios apply. It's currently showing 'Review Due' for every item, irrespective of whether one of the three scenarios has been met.

Comment: Can anyone else help please? The single 'If' elements in my calculated column formula are working fine, but the 'If And' elements aren't. I can't figure out why.