# Calculated column Multiple with multiple IF(IF()) error

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, error, calculated-column-formula

Good morning people. I'm sorry but I need your help.

I have tried to create a calculated column in SharePoint list, depending on two values ​​"height" and "area" corresponds to a number.

I tried the following:

```
IF(AND([Área]<=10;[Alto]<=2);2;IF(AND([Área]<=20;[Alto]<=2);3;IF(AND([Área]<=30;[Alto]<=2);4;IF(AND([Área]>30;[Alto]<=2);5;IF(AND([Alto]<=4;[Área]<=10);6;IF(AND([Alto]<=4;[Área]<=20);7;IF(AND([Alto]<=4;[Área]<=30);8;IF(AND([Alto]<=4;[Área]>30);9;IF(AND([Alto]<=10;[Área]<=10);10;IF(AND([Alto]<=10;[Área]<=20);11;IF(AND([Alto]<=10;[Área]<=30);12;IF(AND([Alto]<=10;[Área]>30);13;IF(AND([Alto]<=20;[Área]<=10);14;IF(AND([Alto]<=20;[Área]<=20);15;IF(AND([Alto]<=20;[Área]<=30);16;IF(AND([Alto]<=20;[Área]>30);17;IF(AND([Alto]>20;[Área]<=10);18;IF(AND([Alto]>20;[Área]<=20);19;IF(AND([Alto]>20;[Área]<=30);20;IF(AND([Alto]>20;[Área]>30);21;))))))))))))))))))))
```

I don't know if there is any syntax error, SharePoint doesn't notify me of that.

Thank you very much in advance for your time.

Comment: Are you not getting expected results while using this formula? Can you add/explain the conditions/logic you are looking for?

Comment: Also, you are trying to use 20 nested `IF` functions which is not supported in SharePoint. Check [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/231997/what-is-the-workaround-for-limit-in-nested-if-statements-in-sharepoint-calculate) and [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/nested-if-in-sharepoint-list/c158697c-9f45-4ce2-9fe0-6b18d9e2d40f) for possible workarounds. let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I didn't know there were only 19 nested if conditions. Thank you very much, I'll try that change in a moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are trying to use 20 nested `IF` functions which is not supported in SharePoint.

Check limitation on Microsoft official documentation at: [IF function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-0a4ad187-dba3-48ae-abe9-bbe3aa6aebca)

**Workarounds**:

So, you have to batch multiple conditions in the bathes of supported limit. Check below links for detailed information and example for this:

1. [What is the workaround for limit in nested if statements in sharepoint calculated column?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/231997/what-is-the-workaround-for-limit-in-nested-if-statements-in-sharepoint-calculate)
2. [Nested If in SharePoint List](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/nested-if-in-sharepoint-list/c158697c-9f45-4ce2-9fe0-6b18d9e2d40f)

**Example (from 1st link)**:

```
if(State="AL","Alabama",
if(State="AK","Alaska",
if(State="AZ","Arizona",
if(State="AR","Arkansas",
if(State="CA","California",
if(State="CO","Colorado",
if(State="CT","Connecticut",
if(State="DE","Delaware",
if(State="FL","Florida",
if(State="GA","Georgia",
if(State="HI","Hawaii",
if(State="ID","Idaho",
if(State="IL","Illinois",
if(State="IN","Indiana",
if(State="IA","Iowa",
if(State="KS","Kansas",
if(State="KY","Kentucky",
if(State="LA","Louisiana",
if(State="ME","Maine",""))))))))))))))))))) &
if(State="MD","Maryland",
if(State="MA","Massachusetts",
if(State="MI","Michigan",
if(State="MN","Minnesota",
if(State="MS","Mississippi",
if(State="MO","Missouri",
if(State="MT","Montana",
if(State="NE","Nebraska",
if(State="NV","Nevada",
if(State="NH","New Hampshire",
if(State="NJ","New Jersey",
if(State="NM","New Mexico",
if(State="NY","New York",
if(State="NC","North Carolina",
if(State="ND","North Dakota",
if(State="OH","Ohio",
if(State="OK","Oklahoma",
if(State="OR","Oregon",
if(State="PA","Pennsylvania",""))))))))))))))))))) &
if(State="RI","Rhode Island",
if(State="SC","South Carolina",
if(State="SD","South Dakota",
if(State="TN","Tennessee",
if(State="TX","Texas",
if(State="UT","Utah",
if(State="VT","Vermont",
if(State="VA","Virginia",
if(State="WA","Washington",
if(State="WV","West Virginia",
if(State="WI","Wisconsin","")))))))))))
```