# Workaround for 19 'IF' in a Calculated Column

Tags: list

I'm hoping the community can help me! I'm relatively comfortable working with Sharepoint Lists, however, formulas are a fairly steep learning curve for me. I have been working on a risk register for work and I am trying to have a calculated column based on 'likelihood' and 'Impact' the result of which, when inputted, will calculate my risk score and be colour coded. After much work and googling I had my formula working up to a point and no further which is when i discovered the limit of 19 IFs. Is there a workaround that i can apply to the following formula to have it all in one calculated column? Formula as follows:

```
=IF(AND([Likelihood]="Remote",[Impact]="Minor"),"Very Low",IF(AND([Likelihood]="Remote",[Impact]="Moderate"),"Very Low",IF(AND([Likelihood]="Remote",[Impact]="Major"),"Very Low",IF(AND([Likelihood]="Remote",[Impact]="Severe"),"Low",IF(AND([Likelihood]="Remote",[Impact]="Critical"),"Low",IF(AND([Likelihood]="Unlikely",[Impact]="Minor"),"Very Low",IF(AND([Likelihood]="Unlikely",[Impact]="Moderate"),"Low",IF(AND([Likelihood]="Unlikely",[Impact]="Major"),"Low",IF(AND([Likelihood]="Unlikely",[Impact]="Severe"),"Low",IF(AND([Likelihood]="Unlikely",[Impact]="Critical"),"Medium",IF(AND([Likelihood]="Possible",[Impact]="Minor"),"Very Low",IF(AND([Likelihood]="Possible",[Impact]="Moderate"),"Low",IF(AND([Likelihood]="Possible",[Impact]="Major"),"Low",IF(AND([Likelihood]="Possible",[Impact]= "Severe"),"Medium",IF(AND([Likelihood]="Possible",[Impact]="Critical"),"Medium to High",IF(AND([Likelihood]="Probable",[Impact]="Minor"),"Very Low",IF(AND([Likelihood]="Probable",[Impact]="Moderate"),"Very Low",IF(AND([Likelihood]="Probable",[Impact]="Major"),"Medium",IF(AND([Likelihood]="Probable",[Impact]="Severe"),"Medium to High",IF(AND([Likelihood]="Probable",[Impact]="Critical"),”High",IF(AND([Likelihood]="Highly Probable",[Impact]="Minor"),"Very Low",IF(AND([Likelihood]="Highly Probable",[Impact]="Moderate"),"Medium",IF(AND([Likelihood]="Highly Probable",[Impact]="Major"),"Medium to High",IF(AND([Likelihood]="Highly Probable",[Impact]="Severe"),"High",IF(AND([Likelihood]="Highly Probable",[Impact]="Critical"),"Very High"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can concatenate more than 19 conditions using `&`. Check: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/231997/what-is-the-workaround-for-limit-in-nested-if-statements-in-sharepoint-calculate. Let me know if it works for you.