# Error in my IF statement

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

My IF statement is shown below and i am using Calculated Function on SharePoint

when the word Traffic Signals is used on [Please select which discipline you require access to?], the row (called Project Discipline) shows up as No instead of the code (_TRS). This is the only one it happens on the 'traffic signal' output and i am unsure on why this is happening, is anyone able to enlighten me?

```
=IF([Please select which discipline you require access to?]="Construction","_CONS",IF([Please select which discipline you require access to?]="Commercial","_COM",IF([Please select which discipline you require access to?]="Drainage","_DRA",IF([Please select which discipline you require access to?]="Information Management","_PIM",IF([Please select which discipline you require access to?]="Document Control","_DC",IF([Please select which discipline you require access to?]="Environment","_ENV",IF([Please select which discipline you require access to?]="Geomatics","_GMT",IF([Please select which discipline you require access to?]="Geotechnical","_GEO",IF(OR([Please select which discipline you require access to?]="Highways",[Please select which discipline you require access to?]="Pavement",[Please select which discipline you require access to?]="Traffic and Economics"),"_HIG",IF(OR([Please select which discipline you require access to?]="Stakeholder",[Please select which discipline you require access to?]="Statutory Process"),"_STK",IF([Please select which discipline you require access to?]="Structures","_STR",IF(OR([Please select which discipline you require access to?]="Technology",[Please select which discipline you require access to?]="Lighting and Electrical"),"_TEC",IF([Please select which discipline you require access to?]="Rail","_RAI",IF([Please select which discipline you require access to?]="Legal","_LEG",IF([Please select which discipline you require access to?]="Traffic Modelling","_TRA",IF([Please select which discipline you require access to?]="Project Wide","_MISC",IF([Please select which discipline you require access to?]="Signs & Markings","_SMK",IF([Please select which discipline you require access to?]="Operational Safety","_OPS",IF(AND([Please select which discipline you require access to?]="Project Management",NOT([ProjectWise Access]="_APP")),IF(OR([Please select which discipline you require access to?]="Traffic Signals","_TRS"),"_PM",""))))))))))))))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using this formula in SP2013 or later versions.

Maximum number of nested IF statement limit is **19**. You must have more than that and due that it's giving you the error.

You can modify your formula as mentioned [What is the workaround for limit in nested if statements in sharepoint calculated column?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/231997/what-is-the-workaround-for-limit-in-nested-if-statements-in-sharepoint-calculate#answer-243949) here to accommodate more IF statements within one formula.